# How to dynamically take the matching value for the input string in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

Here i have a working script which take the relevant values statically by mentioning in the script. I am looking for a solution to dynamically take the values that matches between **input.yml** file **subnetname** and **rules.yml**.

For eg: if there is a new subnet called **net1** defined in the input.yml, then the playbook should be able to match the value and update the rules.yml dynamically and no change should be done to the playbook if there is a new subnetname addition in the input.yml.

**Playbook**

```
- set_fact:
        ruleoutput: >-
                {{
                ruleoutput | default([]) 
                  + [ item | combine({'destCidr': item.destCidr}) | combine({'netname': details.0.Destination})]
                }} 
      loop: "{{ rules | list}}"
      vars:
        po_id: >- 
            {{
              input |items2dict(key_name='subnetname',
                                              value_name='po_id')
            }}
        DNS: "{{ po_id.DNS | default([])}}"  
        NTP: "{{ po_id.NTP | default([])}}" 
        NET: "{{ po_id.NET | default([])}}"
```

**Input.yml**

```
[
    {
        
        "id": "11155588779966",
        "subnetname": "DNS"
        
    },
    {  
        "id": "99996688778855",
        "subnetname": "NTP"
    },
    {
        "id": "123456789101112",
        "subnetname": "NET"
        
    }
]
```

**rules.yml**

```
rules:
         -    rule number: "1" 
              destCidr: "OBJ({{DNS}}) , 10.22.22.0/24"
                  

         -    rule number: "2"
              destCidr: "OBJ({{ NTP }}) , 10.33.33.0/24"
              

         -    rule number: "3"
              destCidr: "OBJ({{ NET }}), GRP({{ NTP }}) , 10.33.33.0/24"
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
    {
        "rule number": "1",
        "destCidr": "OBJ(11155588779966), 10.22.22.0/24 "
    },
    {
        "rule number": "2",
        "destCidr": "OBJ(99996688778855), 10.33.33.0/24"
    },
    {    
        "rule number": "3",
        "destCidr": "OBJ(123456789101112), GRP(99996688778855), 10.33.33.0/24 "
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution:

```
- name: "make this working"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    input: "{{ lookup('file', './input.yml') | from_json }}"
    rules:
      - rule number: "1" 
        destCidr: "OBJ({{po_id.DNS}}) , 10.22.22.0/24"
      - rule number: "2"
        destCidr: "OBJ({{ po_id.NTP }}) , 10.33.33.0/24"
      - rule number: "3"
        destCidr: "OBJ({{ po_id.NET }}), GRP({{ NTP }}) , 10.33.33.0/24"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
         po_id: >- 
            {{
              input |items2dict(key_name='subnetname',
                                              value_name='id')
            }}
    
    - set_fact:
        ruleoutpout: "{{ rules }}"

    - debug:
        var: ruleoutpout
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ruleoutpout": [
        {
            "destCidr": "OBJ(11155588779966) , 10.22.22.0/24",
            "rule number": "1"
        },
        {
            "destCidr": "OBJ(99996688778855) , 10.33.33.0/24",
            "rule number": "2"
        },
        {
            "destCidr": "OBJ(123456789101112), GRP(99996688778855) , 10.33.33.0/24",
            "rule number": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i am actually looking for a dynamic where i dont have to mention the names statically like var in the playbook. For eg: currently there are DNS, NTP, NET var in the playbook tasks. So if i add another subnetname in input yaml as NET1, i dont want to change the playbook task by adding another var as NET1.

Comment: you want input in a file instead? and var DNS,NTP ... are not in playbook?

Comment: just rename the name between {}  (in var rules)  and all is ok  see my answer modified

Comment: Thanks for the solution and it works seamlessly